# What does the asterisk do in "Go"?

Tags: go

I've been going through and trying to understand the examples on the [Go website](http://golang.org/doc/go_tutorial.html) and I keep coming across a special asterisk character in examples like this:

```
s := "hello"
if s[1] != 'e' {
    os.Exit(1)
}
s = "good bye"
var p *string = &s
*p = "ciao"
```

Also, I just noticed, what's with the `&s`? Is it assignment by reference (I might be using PHP talk here)?

Comment: You'll see the asterisk and the ampersand in lower level languages like Go and C.

Comment: C and Go can use special variables, called pointers, that contain memory addresses to objects. Pointers can be passed around and are a compact way to convey access to an object to some other code. In Java, all variables to objects allocated with new operator are reference variables. A reference is similar concept to a pointer variable, except that a pointer is more explicit. The address operator enables taking the address of an object when desired. A pointer variable can be reassigned with different address. A reference variable can only be initialized to an address once.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Im guessing it means the same as in C

`p is a pointer to a string`

The statement `var p *string = &s` would assign the address of the `s` object to `p`

Next line `*p = "ciao"` would change the contents of `s`

See this link from the [Language Design FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#Pointers)

Interestingly, no pointer arithmetic

> Why is there no pointer arithmetic?
> Safety. Without pointer arithmetic
> it's possible to create a language
> that can never derive an illegal
> address that succeeds incorrectly.
> Compiler and hardware technology have
> advanced to the point where a loop
> using array indices can be as
> efficient as a loop using pointer
> arithmetic. Also, the lack of pointer
> arithmetic can simplify the
> implementation of the garbage
> collector.

Comment: So "p" is created as a pointer by declaring it as type "*string" and &s points to the memory location of the variable s.

So why cant I just say p = "ciao" (as opposed to *p)? Would that make a new variable called "p"?

Comment: When you say *p = "ciao", you're saying "take the memory pointed to by p and set it equal to "ciao"". If you said p = "ciao", you'd be trying to say "make p point to the address "ciao"," which doesn't make sense, so it doesn't compile. p = &s says "make p point to the address of s". Maybe that helps?

Comment: why can't the interpreter automatically makes p point to s's address when `p *string = s` instead of having need to specify `&s`

Comment: It also recommend this short post [Pointers in Go. Short tale of asterisk and ampersand](http://piotrzurek.net/2013/09/20/pointers-in-go.html) in order to help you to understand pointers in Go.

Answer (score 162):

`*` attached to a type (`*string`) indicates a pointer to the type.

`*` attached to a variable in an assignment (`*v = ...`) indicates an indirect assignment. That is, change the value pointed at by the variable.

`*` attached to a variable or expression (`*v`) indicates a pointer dereference. That is, take the value the variable is pointing at.

`&` attached to a variable or expression (`&v`) indicates a reference. That is, create a pointer to the value of the variable or to the field.

Comment: It's worth clarifying that for the `*v = ...` case the pointer does not change to point to a new location in memory with a different value, but the underlying value is changed.

Comment: See also * attached to a struct https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693275/what-does-asterisk-struct-notation-mean-in-golang

Answer (score 48):

**Go** *lang* **Addresses, Pointers and Types:**

```
s := "hello"      // type string
t := "bye"        // type string
u := 44           // type int
v := [2]int{1, 2} // type array
q := &s           // type pointer
```

All these [Go](https://go.dev/) variables have an [address in memory](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/1). The distinction between them is string types hold string values, int types hold integer values, and pointer types hold *addresses*. So even variables that hold addresses have their own memory address.

**Pointers:**

Adding `&` before a variable name evaluates to it's address. Or think, "here's my address so you know where to find me."

```
// make p type pointer (to string only) and assign value to address of s
var p *string = &s // type *string
// or
q := &s // shorthand, same deal
```

Adding `*` before a pointer variable dereferences the pointer to the address it is holding. Or think, "pass the action on to the address which is my value."

```
*p = "ciao"   // change s, not p, the value of p remains the address of s

// j := *s    // error, s is not a pointer type, no address to redirect action to
// p = "ciao" // error, can't change to type string

p = &t        // change p, now points to address of t
//p = &u      // error, can't change to type *int

// make r type pointer (to a pointer which is a pointer to a string) and assign value to address of p
var r **string = &p // shorthand: r := &p

w := (  r == &p) // (  r evaluates to address of p) w = true
w =  ( *r == p ) // ( *r evaluates to value of p [address of t]) w = true
w =  (**r == t ) // (**r evaluates to value of t) w = true

// make n type pointer (to string) and assign value to address of t (deref'd p)
n := &*p
o := *&t // meaningless flip-flop, same as: o := t

// point y to array v
y := &v
z := (*y)[0] // dereference y, get first value of element, assign to z (z == 1)
```

Go Play here: http://play.golang.org/p/u3sPpYLfz7

Answer (score 20):

That's how I see it. Different phrasing might help someone to understand it better (you can copy paste that code and examine the output):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // declare a variable of type "int" with the default value "0"
    var y int

    // print the value of y "0"
    fmt.Println(y)

    // print the address of y, something like "0xc42008c0a0"
    fmt.Println(&y)

    // declare a variable of type "int pointer"
    // x may only hold addresses to variables of type "int"
    var x *int

    // y may not simply be assigned to x, like "x = y", because that 
    // would raise an error, since x is of type "int pointer", 
    // but y is of type "int"

    // assign address of y "0xc42008c0a0" as value to x
    x = &y

    // print the value of x "0xc42008c0a0" which is also the address of y
    fmt.Println(x)

    // print the address of x, something like "0xc420030028" 
    // (x and y have different addresses, obviously)
    fmt.Println(&x)

    // x is of type "int pointer" and holds an address to a variable of 
    // type "int" that holds the value "0", something like x -> y -> 0;
    // print the value of y "0" via x (dereference)
    fmt.Println(*x)

    // change the value of y via x
    *x = 1; /* same as */ y = 1

    // print value of y "1"
    fmt.Println(y); /* same as */ fmt.Println(*x)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `*` character is used to define a pointer in both C and Go.  Instead of a real value the variable instead has an address to the location of a value.  The `&` operator is used to take the address of an object.

Comment: Just a note - A memory address is itself a real value. Thats why (in C, but not Go according to the FAQ) you can perform arithmetic on pointers.

Comment: @monadic: what does being a real value have to do with performing arithmetic?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Go, but based on the syntax, it seems that its similar to C - That is a pointer. Its similar to a reference, but lower level and more powerful. It contains the memory address of the item in question. `&a` gets the memory address of a variable and `*a` dereferences it, getting the value at the memory address.

Also, the `*` in the declaration means that it is a pointer.

So yes, its like in PHP in that the value of `s` is changed because `p` and `&s` point to the same block of memory.

Comment: The page the OP linked to seems to reinforce this. "Putting an & in front gives us the address of a unique instance of the value." The example seems to fit this explanation.

Comment: The PHP comparison, though, isn't really accurate. The `&` may represent a slightly similar concept, but their actual usage is different enough (given that PHP doesn't make it easy to get memory addresses) that to say that it's the same concept can be deceptive.

Comment: I know it's not accurate, the PHP website itself says that references are not pointers but references are the closest thing I have to actually truly understanding what pointers are.

Comment: It allows you to do the same thing that PHP references allow you to do in a different way. I was in no way saying that PHP references = Go pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The * in golang as pointers. A pointer holds the memory address of a value.

The type *T is a pointer to a T value. It's zero value is nil.

```
var p *int
```

The & operator generates a pointer to its operand.

```
i := 42
p = &i
```

The * operator denotes the pointer's underlying value.

```
fmt.Println(*p) // read i through the pointer p
*p = 21         // set i through the pointer p
```

This is known as "dereferencing" or "in directing".

Unlike C, Go has no pointer arithmetic.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    i, j := 42, 2701

    p := &i         // point to i
    fmt.Println(*p) // read i through the pointer
    *p = 21         // set i through the pointer
    fmt.Println(i)  // see the new value of i

    p = &j         // point to j
    *p = *p / 37   // divide j through the pointer
    fmt.Println(j) // see the new value of j
}
```