# What does asterisk (*struct) notation mean in golang

Tags: struct, go

```
// NewReaderSize returns a new Reader whose buffer has at least the specified
43  // size. If the argument io.Reader is already a Reader with large enough
44  // size, it returns the underlying Reader.
45  func NewReaderSize(rd io.Reader, size int) *Reader {
46      // Is it already a Reader?
47      b, ok := rd.(*Reader)
48      if ok && len(b.buf) >= size {
49          return b
50      }
51      if size < minReadBufferSize {
52          size = minReadBufferSize
53      }
54      r := new(Reader)
55      r.reset(make([]byte, size), rd)
56      return r
57  }
```

When I use os.Open to open a file

```
dictFile, err := os.Open(file)
```

I'm going to pass dicFile to

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(dictFile)
```

I found the underlying code is using func `NewReaderSize`, but what I can not understand is `rd.(*Reader)`. `Reader` is the struct type contained in package `bufio`. Asterisk followed by a struct is from what I see to get the value from pointer `Reader`, but it is not a pointer, so it does not make sense. Further more, it's using dot operator `rd.(*Reader)`, I totally got confused. What's the meaning of this kind of usage in line 47? What kind of notation it is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`newReaderSize` takes a reader (`io.Reader` interface) and returns a pointer to `Reader` (`struct` defined in `bufio`).

This is called a type assertion:

```
b, ok := rd.(*Reader)
```

From golang spec:

> For an expression x of interface type and a type T, the primary
>   expression **x.(T)** asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored
>   in x is of type T. The notation x.(T) is called a type assertion.

This line is taking that reader and asserting it is a type of `*Reader`, if it succeeds and that `Reader` has buffer big enough its immedietly returned (because it's already what we want).

Answer (score 10):

The syntax in line 47 in your example is a [Type Assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions), it asserts the value of interface variables to be of a specific type. Concretely in your case, the statement

```
b, ok := rd.(*Reader)
```

asserts the underlying value of the interface `rd` to be of type `*Reader` (a pointer to a value of struct `Reader`), giving you `b` of type `*Reader` and a boolean value `ok` that indicates whether the assertion is OK and the underlying value really is of type `*Reader`.

An abstract example ([play](http://play.golang.org/p/cVPaBLuqDy)):

```
type readerA struct {}
func Read(a []byte) (int, error) {}

type readerB struct {}
func Read(a []byte) (int, error) {}

func TakesAReader(r io.Reader) {
   val, ok := r.(*readerA)
   fmt.Println(val, ok)
}

TakesAReader(&readerA{}) // prints &{}, true
TakesAReader(&readerB{}) // prints nil, false
```

So you see, type assertions are just a way to pull out the value that is covered by an interface.