# In golang, what is the difference between & and *

Tags: go

Can someone explain the difference between `&` and `*` in GO lang and provide examples of when `&` and `*` would be used to illustrate the difference? From what I have read, they both relate to accessing a variables memory location however I'm not sure when to use `&` or `*`.

Comment: It's hard to use the wrong one, since it usually won't compile. Just try them out to get a feel for what they do: http://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1

Comment: I second that advice. I couldn't accurately state the rules for the two operators like what's in the spec to save my life but I make them work whenever I need to through trial and error. Most of the time it won't compile if it's wrong because you'll have incompatible types on either side of an assignment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the asterisk do in "Go"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552626/what-does-the-asterisk-do-in-go)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Here is a very simple example, that illustrates how `&` and `*` are used. Note that `*` can be used for two different things 1) to declare a variable to be a pointer 2) to dereference a pointer.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    b := 6 

    var b_ptr *int // *int is used to declare variable
                   // b_ptr to be a pointer to an int

    b_ptr = &b     // b_ptr is assigned the value that is the
                   // address of where variable b is stored

    // Shorthand for the above two lines is:
    // b_ptr := &b

    fmt.Printf("address of b_ptr: %p\n", b_ptr)

    // We can use *b_ptr to get the value that is stored
    // at address b_ptr, known as dereferencing the pointer
    fmt.Printf("value stored at b_ptr: %d\n", *b_ptr)
    
}
```

Result:

```
address of b_ptr: 0xc82007c1f0
value stored at b_ptr: 6
```

Comment: In the context of " func HandleFunc(pattern string, handler func(ResponseWriter, *Request)) ", why does Request dereference a pointer whereas ResponseWriter doesn't?

Comment: That function signature usually looks like this `func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)`, where `w` is `http.ResponseWriter` object and `r` is a pointer to `http.Request` object. There is no dereferencing in this case.

Comment: This is a good example, just use bPtr instead b_ptr as golang recommends avoid using "_" on variable declaration

Answer (score 28):

This helped me understand better, you can run the code in playground and play with it a bit to see how it behaves link here: https://play.golang.org/p/c7jxLJkdRDd (if link is deactivated in the future just copy paste the code below)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    var a = 5
    var p = &a // copy by reference
    var x = a  // copy by value

    fmt.Println("a = ", a)   // a =  5
    fmt.Println("p = ", p)   // p =  0x10414020
    fmt.Println("*p = ", *p) // *p =  5
    fmt.Println("&p = ", &p) // &p =  0x1040c128
    fmt.Println("x = ", x)   // x =  5

    fmt.Println("\n Change *p = 3")
    *p = 3
    fmt.Println("a = ", a)   // a =  3
    fmt.Println("p = ", p)   // p =  0x10414020
    fmt.Println("*p = ", *p) // *p =  3
    fmt.Println("&p = ", &p) // &p =  0x1040c128
    fmt.Println("x = ", x)   // x =  5

    fmt.Println("\n Change a = 888")
    a = 888
    fmt.Println("a = ", a)   // a =  888
    fmt.Println("p = ", p)   // p =  0x10414020
    fmt.Println("*p = ", *p) // *p =  888
    fmt.Println("&p = ", &p) // &p =  0x1040c128
    fmt.Println("x = ", x)   // x =  5

    fmt.Println("\n Change x = 1")
    x = 1
    fmt.Println("a = ", a)   // a =  888
    fmt.Println("p = ", p)   // p =  0x10414020
    fmt.Println("*p = ", *p) // *p =  888
    fmt.Println("&p = ", &p) // &p =  0x1040c128
    fmt.Println("x = ", x)   // x =  1
    
    &p = 3 // error: Cannot assign to &p because this is the address of variable a
}
```

Answer (score 8):

They are the opposite. As explained in [the "Address operators" section of the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators):

> For an operand `x` of type `T`, the address operation `&x` generates a pointer of type `*T` to `x`. […]
>
> For an operand `x` of pointer type `*T`, the pointer indirection `*x` denotes the variable of type `T` pointed to by `x`. If `x` is `nil`, an attempt to evaluate `*x` will cause a run-time panic.

In other words: `&` takes a variable (or other addressable entity) and returns a pointer that points to it, whereas `*` takes a pointer and returns the thing that it points to (unless it's `nil`, meaning it doesn't point to anything).

Comment: Terminological correction: the `&` operation might take a value, not necessary a variable -- a good example is taking an address out of literal, like in `v := &SomeType{}`; the `*` operator returns a value, not a variable. A variable is the name; you can use it in a context which requires a value to refer to that value, but the pointer-dereferencing operator returns a value, and that value may have no variable bound to it.

Comment: @kostix: Good point, thanks; fixed. I'm too used to the Java spec, where any lvalue is called a "variable". :-P

Answer (score 7):

`&` is the address of operator. `*` represent a pointer in some cases, in others it is used as the 'dereference operator'.

So basically, if you do `p := &SometType{}` the address of operator is used to return the address of the object created with the composite literal statement `SomeType{}` if I were to remove it, I would no longer have a reference and instead be assigning the value directly to `p`. In this case `p` will be a `*SomeType` because that is the types who's address I took. If I declare a type with `*` in front of it, I'm designating it as a pointer to that type.

Now the last remaining use is as a the deference operator, you don't use this much in Go in my experience but it was super common in C and C++. This is used to return the actual value rather, it's most often leverage for assignment. Because like if I have `p` and it is a `*SomeType` and locally I want to assign to an instance of `SomeType` then I'll need the following statement `someType := *p` so that the value is assigned to my value type.

Hope that explanation helps. It's not the most technical one, rather my goal is to provide understanding of the common uses.

Answer (score 7):

`&` makes a pointer from a variable.

`*` "fetches" the value stored where a pointer points to.

For types, `var *type` means "*var is of the type *type*" (and without a variable, it simply means "a pointer to something of *type*".

Answer (score 0):

- `&` is Used on the right side of the operand to return the address (actual) value.
- `*` is Used on the left side of the operand to resolve the address value.

```
    type V struct {
        E map[string]string
    }
    
    //Caller recieves the resolved value
    func New() *V {
        //Returns the address of the struct
        return &V{E: make(map[string]string)} 
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

**b *int** 
// creating variable

***b = 5**
// assigning value

**fmt.Println(*b)**
// getting value

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -7):

& and * is used mainly in functions:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    name     string
    ageYears int
    areDays  int
}

func main() {
    john := Person{name: "John", ageYears: 46}
    toDays(&john)
    fmt.Println(john) //{John 46 16790}
    toDays2(john)
    fmt.Println(john) //{John 46 16790}
}

func toDays(p *Person) {
    p.areDays = p.ageYears * 365
}

func toDays2(p Person) {
    p.areDays = -1
}
```